# how to calculate average from array in wcf service

Tags: c#

why it doesn't give me  average 3?

```
public  double total = 0;
public  double avg = 0;

public double[] Yahoo = { 1, 2, 3, 4,5 };

for (int i = 0; i < Yahoo.Length; i++)
{ 
    total += Yahoo[i]; 
}
avg = total / Yahoo.Length;
```

Comment: It works for me (assuming you're actually placing the code in a context where it actually compiles).

Comment: What is the problem? What output are you getting?

Comment: are you sure that the array is correct I suspect the example and your real code is more different

Comment: im getting some 437 value insted of 3 and putting in Company.WeekAvg = avg;

Comment: Are you trying to compare it to 3.0? (avg == 3.0)

Comment: Is your total global by any chance? Do you reset it before calculating the average?

Comment: no  i just want to get avg dynamically (lets say if i calculate my average 1+2+3+4+5= 15 which is total and avg = 15/ 5 which is array length) and it suppose to get answer is 3

Comment: yes my total is global and its outside of method

Comment: @user3486586 That's your problem - you never reset the total, so this is why it keeps growing. Please check if it helps so I can promote my comment to an answer.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I ran this console application:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double total = 0;
        double avg = 0;

        double[] Yahoo = { 1, 2, 3, 4,5 };

        for (int i = 0; i < Yahoo.Length; i++)
        {
            total += Yahoo[i];
        }

        avg = total / Yahoo.Length;

        Console.WriteLine(avg);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

and I got 3.

However you could use LINQ for that you want:

```
Yahoo.Average();
```

Ah, in order to use this method, you have to set this on the top of your source code file the following using statement:

```
using System.Linq;
```

**Note** One thing that seems odd to me, is the way you have declared your variables

```
public double total = 0;
public double avg = 0;
public double[] Yahoo = { 1, 2, 3, 4,5 };
```

since those should be declared in a method, they shouldn't have an access modifier. That's wrong.

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's question.

Comment: thank you yahoo.average() worked for me

Comment: @GrantWinney if those variables are declared in a method, can they have an access modifier? If they are class variables, yeap they should  have an access modifier. But if they didn't?

Comment: all i needed was   public double[] Yahoo = { 1, 2, 3, 4,5 };                 Yahoo.Average();

Comment: @user3486586 You welcome ! However I didn't get what was your error?

Comment: my error was it wasnt calculating the average correctly

Comment: @user3486586 your program was something like the console app that I posted, or it was different?

Comment: i was using WCF Service in c#(needed in WCF service)

Comment: @user3486586 i'm glad since that works for you. But simultaneously I am trying to figure out why your version didn't work.